# Trying to read MIRC logs in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, mirc

I am trying to make a page that lets my admins read the MIRC Log files from our bot...I am having the hardest time trying to get this to work for some reason...i have taken bits and pieces of code to get what i have working...but it still either doesn't display at all OR after about 200 lines, it stops reading each line but instead make it one big mess of text...here is what i have for code

```
Protected Sub bView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bView.Click
    Response.Write(Server.MapPath("~/mirc/logs/" & lbfiles.SelectedItem.Text))
    lFileOut.Text = ""
    Try
        Dim FILENAME As String = Server.MapPath("~/mirc/logs/" & lbfiles.SelectedItem.Text)
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim cont As String
        Do
            cont = objStreamReader.ReadLine()
            lFileOut.Text = lFileOut.Text & cont & "<br>"
            'Response.Write(cont)
        Loop Until cont Is Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is a test file i have been testing everything on...it just doesn't do anything nor does it throw any error...i am completely stumped on this one.

[test file](http://pervsgame.com/other%20stuff/testdoc.rar)

Answer (score -1):

Do this: go into your server, in your root folder make a new folder called whatever you want then go into your mIRC script goto tools/options/logging change directory to the new folder you made click save.. that way you or anyone you want to view all logs from your mIRC script can view by going to www.yoursite.net/foldername and it will show you the list of all logged things, status and room window conversations...

If you want to know how to code it so your opers can just have a clickable link in their remotes I can do that for you as well.... hope this helps